# Stop mp3 file from streaming in browsers

Tags: apache, browser, download, mp3

I have an mp3 on an apache server. I want it to be downloaded as a file when a user visits the link. Instead quicktime, or google chromes media player will try and stream it.

Is there a fix for this with headers? Or is the only option so 'right click save as'?

**Edit** Here is my header. Safari has stopped streaming, but chrome contines to do it.
Chrome seems to be ignoring this:

I can see the header has been changed correctly:

```
Date    Wed, 04 Aug 2010 00:14:35 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.11
Last-Modified   Tue, 03 Aug 2010 04:37:01 GMT
Etag    "2bbd692-79597d-48ce3de3f5540"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  7952765
Content-Disposition attachment
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    audio/mpeg
```

Is there anything else in the header that would cause this?

**Edit** Doing some research I found this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=76de4f53f43f03d3&hl=en
Looks like there might be a bug in chrome preventing it from downloading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to set the [`Content-Disposition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) response header to "attachment", and probably the "filename" field as well.

Example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.mp3;
```

To accomplish this directly in Apache, try putting the following in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$">
  ForceType audio/mpeg
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*/?([^/]*)$" FILENAME=$1
  Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e"
  UnsetEnv FILENAME
</FilesMatch>
```

**EDIT:**

Added filename field to Apache configuration example, borrowed from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files/101966#101966). You should be aware, however, of potential problems caused by filenames with non-US-ASCII characters in them: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http).

Alternatively, you could use a generic constant filename (since you know the extension already) like `song.mp3`, but this might not be an option depending on your circumstances.

A third option would be to create a script to serve these MP3s, which can set the header and take care of stripping unwanted characters out of the filename.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I found this article on how to force downloads http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/06-08-2007/force-a-pdf-to-download

Comment: Chrome is ignoring this, don't know why. Pasted the header above.

Comment: @Keyo: Hmm... Try replacing the `audio/mpeg` mime type with `application/octet-stream`

Comment: I looked up the header support on this page. http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#attwithfilenameandextparam

Looks like I need to include filename and ext. Do you know how to set these from .htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for that, but the filename comes up blank in the header. I only have on file I will make it static.

Comment: No luck with chrome, giving up. Thing is fubar.

Comment: Works for me as of today in Chrome 21.0.1180.89 on Mac OSX 10.7.4 :)