# Wordpress Download Link for Audio File

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am using the plugin mb.miniAudioPlayer to handle audio player on my wordpress site.

It allows for nice download button that does not require a "right click and save as"  The only problem is that is does not save the file as expected.

I get mp3 file with no filename or anything.  even when I rename the file to filename.mp3 it is not playable.

The plugin dev says it is something wrong with my server.  I am totally lost.  any help would be appreciated.

example page is here [link](http://jonbennett.co/lab/gym-name5-team-name-2012-2013-descriptor-2/)

Response from dev here [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/file-names?replies=2#post-3536379)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any `mp3` file link to download but if it's a server side problem then it could be a `myme-type` issue. Your server must be configured to handle the `mp3` files. Add following code in your `.htaccess` file in the server root, it may solve the problem.

```
<Files *.mp3>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
</Files>
```

Also remember that your `mp3` files on the server must have `mp3` extension. Also take a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401650/stop-mp3-file-from-streaming-in-browsers).

Comment: when I have a .mp3 hyperlink it works as you would expect. it opens in a new window and plays in the browser.  I want the download icon to automatically download the file as you would expect.  It's just not working properly.  The dev says it is something with my server.  I just can't figure it out.  any further help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: This may help. This is the code that inserts the audio player from my template file  `<div class="entry">
<a href="  <?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){
        get_custom_field_value('audio', true); 
} ?> "></a>`